# Understanding closures or best way to take udf registrations' code out of main and put in utils

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql, closures

This is more of a Scala  concept doubt than Spark. I have this Spark initialization code :

```
object EntryPoint {
   val spark = SparkFactory.createSparkSession(...
   val funcsSingleton = ContextSingleton[CustomFunctions] { new CustomFunctions(Some(hashConf)) }
   lazy val funcs = funcsSingleton.get
   //this part I want moved to another place since there are many many UDFs
   spark.udf.register("funcName", udf {funcName _ })
}
```

The other class, CustomFunctions looks like this

```
class CustomFunctions(val hashConfig: Option[HashConfig], sark: Option[SparkSession] = None) {
     val funcUdf = udf { funcName _ }
     def funcName(colValue: String) = withDefinedOpt(hashConfig) { c =>
     ...}
}
```

^ class is wrapped in Serializable interface using ContextSingleton which is defined like so

```
class ContextSingleton[T: ClassTag](constructor: => T) extends AnyRef with Serializable {
   val uuid = UUID.randomUUID.toString
   @transient private lazy val instance = ContextSingleton.pool.synchronized {
ContextSingleton.pool.getOrElseUpdate(uuid, constructor)
   }
   def get = instance.asInstanceOf[T]
}
object ContextSingleton {
   private val pool = new TrieMap[String, Any]()
   def apply[T: ClassTag](constructor: => T): ContextSingleton[T] = new ContextSingleton[T](constructor)
   def poolSize: Int = pool.size
   def poolClear(): Unit = pool.clear()
}
```

Now to my problem, I want to not have to explicitly register the udfs as done in the EntryPoint app. I create all udfs as needed in my CustomFunctions class and then register dynamically only the ones that I read from user provided config. What would be the best way to achieve it? Also, I want to register the required udfs outside the main app but that throws my the infamous `TaskNotSerializable` exception. Serializing the big CustomFunctions is not a good idea, hence wrapped it up in ContextSingleton but my problem of registering udfs outside cannot be solved that way. Please suggest the right approach.